# Component Alignment using Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

'm starting with React and I'm using material-ui to build forms, I'm not able to solve a detail of alignment in the components, as the Form has many fields, it gets a little "messy", so I would like to see if it is improving the alignment of the components.

The detail is that when there are 2 columns (xs = 1 and xs = 5 - "6 columns"), it does not give the same alignment as the row below, when also 2 two columns (xs = 2 and xs = 4 - "6 columns ").

The closest I found researching about it, was on this link, but I still couldn't get this detail right.

[How do I layout forms in MaterialUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978169/how-do-i-layout-forms-in-materialui)

Below a snippet of Project code and a print, trying to better illustrate the problem.

```
 [return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={0}> {/*Início Primeiro Container ( Linha )*/}
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                name="conCodigo"
                                label="Código"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCodigo}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={5}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                name="conNome"
                                label="Nome Contribuinte"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conNome}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.conNome}
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Fone 1"
                                name="conFone1"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conFone1}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.conFone1}
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Fone 2"
                                name="conFone2"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conFone2}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Fone 3"
                                name="conFone3"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conFone3}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid> {/*Fim Primeiro Container */}
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={0}> 
                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Contato"
                                name="conContato"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conContato}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                label="Fís./Jur."
                                name="conFisJur"
                                value={values.conFisJur}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getFisJur()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="CPF/CNPJ"
                                name="conCpfCnpj"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCpfCnpj}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Teste"
                                name="conCpfCnpj"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCpfCnpj}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Grid container> {/*Início Segundo Container */}
                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="E-mail"
                                name="conEmail"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conEmail}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.conEmail}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                name="conTipoDoac"
                                label="Tipo Doação"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conTipoDoac}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getTipoDoacao()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                name="conCategoria"
                                label="Categoria"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCategoria}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getCategoria()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                name="conSexo"
                                label="Sexo"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conSexo}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getGenero()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid> {/*Fim Segundo Container */}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>]
```

...
[1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyWOm.png

Comment: The image in the illustration on the screen was posted wrong, you need to copy the link to view, sorry for the English, I write with Google Translate ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add spacing to you `grid container` make your columns even in the layout. I see you have the `3 grid container` copy the code below and this should fix the layout.

```
 <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}>
 <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> 
 <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried to use it this way too before (with alignContent = 'stretch'), but unfortunately it remains the same as shown in the previous image, in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyWOm.png

Comment: Yes, the line looks like this: <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}>

Comment: Make sure you add that line `<Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}>` to all of your containers. And wrap them all in with add `<Container component="main" maxWidth="xl">` before your form `<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`  and close after form close tag `</Container>`

Comment: OK, I'm stopping here today, tomorrow I'm going to make this adjustment, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below code and try again. Thanks

```
[return (
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xl">
   <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent>
                <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> {/*Início Primeiro Container ( Linha )*/}
                    <Grid item xs={1}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            name="conCodigo"
                            label="Código"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conCodigo}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={5}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            name="conNome"
                            label="Nome Contribuinte"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conNome}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            error={errors.conNome}
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            label="Fone 1"
                            name="conFone1"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conFone1}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            error={errors.conFone1}
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            label="Fone 2"
                            name="conFone2"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conFone2}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            label="Fone 3"
                            name="conFone3"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conFone3}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid> {/*Fim Primeiro Container */}
                <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> 
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            label="Contato"
                            name="conContato"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conContato}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Select
                            label="Fís./Jur."
                            name="conFisJur"
                            value={values.conFisJur}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            options={contribuinteService.getFisJur()}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            label="CPF/CNPJ"
                            name="conCpfCnpj"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conCpfCnpj}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            label="Teste"
                            name="conCpfCnpj"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conCpfCnpj}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent>
                <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> {/*Início Segundo Container */}
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <Controls.Input
                            label="E-mail"
                            name="conEmail"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conEmail}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            error={errors.conEmail}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Select
                            name="conTipoDoac"
                            label="Tipo Doação"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conTipoDoac}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            options={contribuinteService.getTipoDoacao()}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Select
                            name="conCategoria"
                            label="Categoria"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conCategoria}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            options={contribuinteService.getCategoria()}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        <Controls.Select
                            name="conSexo"
                            label="Sexo"
                            size={sizeBox}
                            value={values.conSexo}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            options={contribuinteService.getGenero()}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid> {/*Fim Segundo Container */}
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
       </Form>
      </Container>
)
```

Comment: I did it like you said, and showed it now, but he is still "stubborn", (laughs), he is still the same. I put before Form:<Container component="main" maxWidth="xl">
                                          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>...

Comment: And in the end I closed the container tag normally:    </Form> </Container>

Comment: Great, I'm glad this solve the problem for you. Do you mind supporting my solution by clicking on the up arrow and mark it, please? Thank you

Comment: Hello, I'm glad to be able to contribute to the score, but as I don't post much here, my score is very low, and from the message I saw, they are valid, but they do not reflect publicly.

Comment: But despite the efforts so far, there has not been a certain alignment within the Layout yet, I will simplify the Program, so it is easier to try to solve it, I think this is important, it would also be useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the alignment worked, the problem is that it had an additional layout, used in "cascade". Where it is 100% it was 90% before, so it was out of alignment, even adjusting the Layout correctly, as indicated in the previous Answer.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiFormControl-root': {
            width: '100%',
            margin: theme.spacing(0)
        }
    },
}))
```

I will leave the code here, so it can be useful for others who go through the problem.

Are made in 3 separate files to compose the entire layout

Modal:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, makeStyles, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import Controls from "./controls/Controls";
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    dialogWrapper: {
        padding: theme.spacing(0),
        position: 'absolute',
        top: theme.spacing(0)
    },
    dialogTitle: {
        paddingRight: '0px'
    }
}))

export default function Modal(props) {

    const { title, widthForm, children, openModal, setOpenModal } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Dialog open={openModal} maxWidth={widthForm} classes={{ paper: classes.dialogWrapper }}>
            <DialogTitle className={classes.dialogTitle}>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" component="div" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                        {title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Controls.ActionButton
                        color="secondary"
                        onClick={()=>{setOpenModal(false)}}>
                        <CloseIcon />
                    </Controls.ActionButton>
                </div>
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent dividers>
                {children}
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

useForm:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export function useForm(initialFValues, validateOnChange = false, validate) {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFValues);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        })
        if (validateOnChange)
            validate({ [name]: value })
    }

    const resetForm = () => {
        setValues(initialFValues);
        setErrors({})
    }

    return {
        values,
        setValues,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange,
        resetForm

    }
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiFormControl-root': {
            width: '100%',
            margin: theme.spacing(0)
        }
    },
}))

export function Form(props) {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const { children, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off" {...other}>
            {props.children}
        </form>
    )
}
```

And the Form with the Fields itself:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Divider } from 'react'
import { Grid, Container, FormGroup } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import Controls from "../../components/controls/Controls";
import { useForm, Form } from '../../components/useForm';
import * as contribuinteService from "../../services/ContribuinteService";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      marginBottom: 5
    },
    bullet: {
      display: 'inline-block',
      margin: '0 2px',
      transform: 'scale(0.8)',
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    pos: {
      marginBottom: 12,
    },
    menuPaper: {
        maxHeight: 50
    }
  });

const initialFValues = {
    id: 0,
    conCodigo: '',
    conNome: '',
    conFone1: '',
    conFone2: '',
    conFone3: '',
    conEmail: '',
    conSexo: '',
    conTipoDoac: '',
    conCategoria: ''
}

export default function ContribuinteForm(props) {
    const { addOrEdit, recordForEdit, setOpenModal, sizeBox } = props
    const classes = useStyles();

    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
        let temp = { ...errors }
        if ('conNome' in fieldValues)
            temp.conNome = fieldValues.conNome ? "" : "O Nome é Obrigatório!"
        if ('conEmail' in fieldValues)
            temp.conEmail = (/$^|.+@.+..+/).test(fieldValues.conEmail) ? "" : "E-mail não é Válido."
        if ('conFone1' in fieldValues)
            temp.conFone1 = fieldValues.conFone1.length > 8 ? "" : "Mínimo 9 Dig requerido."
        setErrors({
            ...temp
        })

        if (fieldValues == values)
            return Object.values(temp).every(x => x == "")
    }

    const {
        values,
        setValues,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange,
        resetForm
    } = useForm(initialFValues, true, validate);

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validate()) {
            addOrEdit(values, resetForm);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (recordForEdit != null)
            setValues({
                ...recordForEdit
            })
    }, [recordForEdit])

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    {/*Início Primeiro Container ( Linha )*/}
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> 
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                name="conCodigo"
                                label="Código"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCodigo}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={5}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                name="conNome"
                                label="Nome Contribuinte"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conNome}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.conNome}
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Fone 1"
                                name="conFone1"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conFone1}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.conFone1}
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Fone 2"
                                name="conFone2"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conFone2}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Fone 3"
                                name="conFone3"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conFone3}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid> {/*Fim Primeiro Container */}
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> 
                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Contato"
                                name="conContato"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conContato}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                label="Fís./Jur."
                                name="conFisJur"
                                value={values.conFisJur}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getFisJur()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="CPF/CNPJ"
                                name="conCpfCnpj"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCpfCnpj}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="Teste"
                                name="conCpfCnpj"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCpfCnpj}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> {/*Início Segundo Container */}
                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <Controls.Input
                                label="E-mail"
                                name="conEmail"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conEmail}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.conEmail}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                name="conTipoDoac"
                                label="Tipo Doação"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conTipoDoac}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getTipoDoacao()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                name="conCategoria"
                                label="Categoria"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conCategoria}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getCategoria()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controls.Select
                                name="conSexo"
                                label="Sexo"
                                size={sizeBox}
                                value={values.conSexo}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                options={contribuinteService.getGenero()}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid> {/*Fim Segundo Container */}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item lg={12}>
                            <TextField id="standard-basic2" label="Observação 1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item lg={12}>
                            <TextField id="standard-basic2" label="Observação 2" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>   
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardActions>
                    <Grid container alignContent='stretch' spacing={1}> {/*Início Terceiro Container */}
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <div>
                                <Controls.Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    text="Salvar" 
                                />
                                <Controls.Button
                                    text="Sair"
                                    color="default"
                                    onClick={()=>{setOpenModal(false)}}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid> {/*Fim Terceiro Container */}
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        </Form>
    )
}
```

And finally the print of how the screen looked after the adjustment, thank you very much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmWQN.png)